# How to run perl or shell scripts in windows in secured environment without strawberry perl or Cygwin

Tags: perl, shell, scripting

I need to write perl or shell scripts in windows environment for automation. Please suggest some freeware.

For perl I tried padre perl but post installation it requires connection with CPAN which my proxy doesn't allows.Hence its unable to identify modules once I run perl scripts.

Also for running Shell scripts  I tried cygwin but its unable to identify loop statements while running shell scripts.

How should I go ahead?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you intent on writing your code in Perl or Shell?  Are Batch & PowerShell off the table?

Comment: why can't you use Strawberry? it's free and doesn't require CPAN

Comment: @beasy I guess Strawberry perl also don't have all the modules present and needed to be installed from CPAN. Like `Mail::Sender` can't locate Mail/Sender.pm in `@inc` and need to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use Activestate? I think is the best perl packaged system for Windows.

Here's the link for the free community edition:

http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads

As for editors, you can also use Komod Edit: http://komodoide.com/komodo-edit/

Comment: Because a proxy that disallows access to CPAN is *sure* to allow access to the PPM Repository....  =/

Comment: @tjd  I tried using activeperl to run my script. I get the following error to install any module ppm install File::Slurp, get the following error `Downloading ActiveState Package Repository packlist...failed 500 Can't connect t
o ppm4.activestate.com:80`....... Is this also bcos of firewall/proxy settings?

Comment: @Joybanerjee Most likely.  I expect you've already set your http_proxy environment variable.  What you *really* need to do is get your proxy admin on board with your issue.